# Dynamically Updating a Generic Row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a way to update rowtypes generically so that I can insert the same groups of data for different tables.

My requirements are to take tables that have very similar columns like ones below.

```
create table storedNumber(myNumber number, userName varchar2(4000), userId number, birthDate date);
/
create table storedVarchar(myVarchar varchar2(4000), userName varchar2(4000), userId number, birthDate date);
```

From there I want to create a generic solution that will update rowtypes with the three identical columns there (userName, userId, birthDate). Imagining a solution and use case looks something like the following.

```
procedure UpdateRowWithUserInfo(in_tableName varchar2, in_rowType in out generic_row(?), in_userInfo userInfo) is
begin
  in_rowType('userName') := in_userInfo.userName;
  in_rowType('userId') := in_userInfo.userId;
  in_rowType('birthDate') := in_userInfo.birthDate;
end;
/
declare
  l_userInfo   userInfo;
  l_numberRow  storedNumber%rowtype;
  l_varcharRow storedVarchar%rowtype;
begin
  -- This returns a userInfo object from the id with the userName, userId, and birthDate populated
  l_userInfo := get_userInfo(123);

  -- Getting some data for the rows
  l_numberRow.myNumber := 42;
  l_varcharRow.myVarchar := 'Hello World';

  -- This function should update the input row's columns with the input user info
  UpdateRowWithUserInfo('storedNumber', l_numberRow, l_userInfo);
  UpdateRowWithUserInfo('storedVarchar', l_varcharRow, l_userInfo);
end;
```

Would something like this be possible with Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Oracle's object-relational features.

```
create or replace type userInfo is object
(
    userName  varchar2(100),
    userId    number,
    birthDate date
) not final;

create or replace type userInfoWithNumber under userInfo
(
    myNumber number
) not final;

create or replace type userInfoWithVarchar under userInfo
(
    myVarchar2 varchar2(100)
) not final;

create or replace procedure UpdateRowWithUserInfo(targetUserInfo in out userInfo, sourceUserInfo in userinfo) is
begin
    targetUserInfo.userName  := sourceUserInfo.userName;
    targetUserInfo.userId    := sourceUserInfo.userId;
    targetUserInfo.birthDate := sourceUserInfo.birthDate;
end;
/

declare
    l_userInfo   userInfo; 
    l_numberRow  userInfoWithNumber;
    l_varcharRow userInfoWithVarchar;
begin
    l_userInfo   := userInfo('A', 1, date '2000-01-01');
    l_numberRow  := userInfoWithNumber('B', 2, date '2000-01-02', 42);
    l_varcharRow := userInfoWithVarchar('C', 3, date '2000-01-03', 'Hello World');

    UpdateRowWithUserInfo(l_numberRow, l_userInfo);
    UpdateRowWithUserInfo(l_varcharRow, l_userInfo);

    --Print new values to demonstrate that they have changed.
    --Values were originally "B" and "C" but will now be "A".
    dbms_output.put_line(l_numberRow.username);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_varcharRow.username);
end;
/
```

---

This isn't completely dynamic though since the objects must be created on the schema.  An even more generic solution could be created using the [AnyTypes](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30023).

But 99% of the time I would recommend against using either one of those options.  Oracle works best when the tables, rows, and columns are "dumb" (i.e. relational).  Make the *schema* or the *program* smart.  Instead of creating generic objects, create dynamic code that can modify your simple tables.